# html object margin-right no function

Tags: html, css

I am building a leaflet map and want to add a logo and a headline above the map. When trying to define the position, I noticed that only the `margin-left` command works. The `margin-right` command just gets "ignored". I currently only use the `margin-left` command to pretty much get around the problem, but when I try to minimize my browser the alignment just is not right anymore.

Here´s some code from my html elements:

```
<!--headline -->
<h2 style="postion:absolute; top:10px; margin-left:7.5%;">Maschinentechnische Anlagen </h2>

<!--logo + position-->
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; margin-left: 89%">   <!-- ideal would be margin-right: 7.5% -->
<img src="images/DBlogo.png" width="50"/> </div>


<!--map + position-->
<div style="height:860px; width:85%; margin-top:auto; margin-left:7.5%; margin-right:7.5%;" id="map"></div>
```

Note: The `margin-right` part when defining the map also does not have any impact, but that is not that big of a problem since it is already defined enough with the width part

Comment: The margin should appear, wether or not it has any effect on the layout of your page depends on the surrounding elements.

Comment: What do you mean with appear ? At the moment i dont get an error when using the command in my code, but it has no effect on the position of the object.

Comment: Use `top left right bottom` instead of margins when using positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this situation margin-right is ignored because margin-left is smaller than the necessary size for margin-right: 7.5

you can't have the element at margin-left 89% and margin-right: 7.5%

To place the element at right 7.5 you can directly use right: 7.5%

```css
div, h2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!--headline -->
<h2 style="postion:absolute; top:10px; margin-left:7.5%;">Maschinentechnische Anlagen </h2>

<!--logo + position-->
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; right: 7.5%">   <!-- ideal would be margin-right: 7.5% -->
<img src="images/DBlogo.png" width="50"/> </div>


<!--map + position-->
<div style="height:860px; width:85%; margin-top:auto; margin-left:7.5%; margin-right:7.5%;" id="map"></div>
```